# Ansible single task variable on top of global variable

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook where I am configuring environment variables for multiple hosts.

these are the global vars set in `defaults\main.yml`:

```
environment:
  http_proxy: blabla
  https_proxy: blabla
```

Now I have a single task where I need to set another environment variable for the python library. 
However, when I set the environment var for that single task it overwrites the global environment vars.

```
- name: some task
    command: command
    environment:
      ENV_VAR: "blabla"
```

I want the ENV_VAR for the single task to be added on top of the global vars. But is that even possible?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html
this page didn't give me anything conclusive.

Could I use the `with_items` option to achieve this possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following playbook demonstrates a possible implementation for your requirement using the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) associated with [`default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables). Run this with `-v` option to see output of shell commands:

```
---
- name: Parse several results as json strings
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  # This will automatically combine `default_env` (default to empty if it does not exists)
  # with `more_env` if this latest var is defined somewhere
  environment: "{{ default_env | default({}) | combine(more_env | default({})) }}"

  vars:
    # Define default environment variables
    default_env:
      http_proxy: blabla
      https_proxy: blabla

  tasks:
    - name: Show some vars
      vars:
        # Inject more environment variables for this task
        more_env:
          toto: titi
      shell: |-
        echo $http_proxy
        echo $https_proxy
        echo $toto

    - name: Same with default env
      shell: |-
        echo $http_proxy
        echo $https_proxy
        echo $toto
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml -v

PLAY [Default env override] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show some vars] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo $http_proxy\necho $https_proxy\necho $toto", "delta": "0:00:00.002207", "end": "2020-01-07 09:57:30.178989", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-01-07 09:57:30.176782", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "blabla\nblabla\ntiti", "stdout_lines": ["blabla", "blabla", "titi"]}

TASK [Same with default env] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo $http_proxy\necho $https_proxy\necho $toto", "delta": "0:00:00.001875", "end": "2020-01-07 09:57:30.626163", "rc": 0, "start": "2020-01-07 09:57:30.624288", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "blabla\nblabla", "stdout_lines": ["blabla", "blabla"]}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```